# How can I configure my EarlGrey test to wait for a view or an event?

Tags: ios, testing, functional-testing, earlgrey

I'm writing a test where I need to wait for a particular view to show up in my UI using the `EarlGrey` UI Testing framework. So, I looked at the docs [here](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/api.md#greycondition) and am trying to achieve this using `GREYCondition`. But it seems as though `GREYCondition` requires a particular condition check or so to be used. Can anyone advise me as to what the format of the condition is? Is there any way by which I can pass in my view to the condition to make it wait for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically you shouldn’t have to wait for a particular view as EarlGrey’s built-in synchronization should automatically do that for you. There are various settings in [GREYConfiguration](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/EarlGrey/Common/GREYConfiguration.m) that can be tweaked to increase (or decrease) the extent to which EarlGrey synchronizes. If none of those settings work, you can add explicit synchronization with something like the `GREYCondition` that you’ve created and use the top-level EarlGrey API to determine whether a view exists.

```
GREYCondition *waitForFoo = [[GREYCondition conditionWithName:@"wait for Foo" block:^BOOL{
  NSError *error;
  // Checking if a view with accessibility ID "Foo" exists:
  [[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@”Foo”)]  
      assertWithMatcher:grey_notNil() error:&error];
  return error == nil;
}];

// Wait until 5 seconds for the view.
BOOL fooExists = [waitForFoo waitWithTimeout:5];
if (fooExists) {
  // Interact with Foo.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!